# Default dropdown value on load from hyperlink with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink

I did some searching and couldn't find an exact answer on how to do this (especially for a noob like me) I would like to set a dropdown value on page load based off a variable in the href hyperlink.

Example with default dropdown: mywebsite.com&value=4

This would apply the dropdown item associated with value 4 when the page loaded.Below is the HTML for the drop down selector but I currently have no JavaScript for it. Is it possible for it to pull a variable from hyperlink? Thanks for any help.

```
<select id="subject" name="subjectlist" size="1" onchange="SetActivity();">
<option value="1^Non-Urgent Medical Question">Non-Urgent Medical Question</option>
<option value="2^Medication Question">Medication Question</option>
<option value="3^Test Results Question">Test Results Question</option>
<option value="4^Visit Follow-Up Question">Visit Follow-Up Question</option>
<option value="5^Medical Record Question / Correction">Medical Record Question / Correction</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have control of the URL, you can change the format and use a hash.

So for `value=4`, the URL is: http://example.com/#value=4

```
if (window.location.hash.length > 0){
    var matches = window.location.hash.match(/value=([0-9]+)/i);
    if (matches.length > 1){
        var value = matches[1];
        $("#subject option[value^='"+value+"^']").attr('selected', true);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could `filter` the options based on value. Safer than the above code:

```
if (window.location.hash.length > 0){
    var matches = window.location.hash.match(/value=([0-9]+)/i);
    if (matches.length > 1){
        var value = matches[1];
        $("#subject option").filter(function(){
            return $(this).val().indexOf(value+'^') === 0;
        }).attr('selected', true);
    }
}
```

If you don't want to use a hash (#), you could use `window.location.href` instead. You'd just modify the `RegEx` a bit (so it's guaranteed to be at the end of the URL).

Comment: I think this will actually work! Did some quick messy testing in a console and it fired right. Thanks man!